# Command Line PHP with shell_exec works for root but not others

Tags: php, linux, permissions, command-line-interface

I have a very simple script that is to test if running a shell_exec (or backtick operator) basically works:

```
#!/usr/bin/php5
<?php

echo "This is a PHP script\n";
echo `ls -l /home/stoysnet/`;
```

Unless I run this as root, it always gives me:

```
$ ./foo.php 
This is a PHP script

Warning: _shell_exec(): Permission Denied in /home/stoysnet/foo.php on line 5
```

I've tried running this via PHP in a few different ways, but I always get the same error. However, when I put the script into a subdirectory of `/etc/` owned by `root:root` and executed as `root` it works.

What gives?

**Update:** Just to clarify:

- I am trying to run it as the `stoysnet` user via the command line. I am able to execute the command being passed to `shell_exec` via the same session.
- If I move the script to `/etc/somedir/` and execute is as `root`, it works as expected.
- The script itself runs, just not the backtick operator or `shell_exec` part
- Execution permissions are set, and `777` doesn't work either.

Comment: What are the permissions/ownership on the /home/stoysnet directory? To be able to 'ls' a directory (eg: list/enumerate its contents), the user executing the script has to have execute permissions on the directory (either as the owner, the group, or as 'everyone').

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this script as a different user than `stoysnet`? What happens when you do run `ls -l /home/stoysnet` as the same user that you're executing the PHP script as?

Seems like you need to run the script as a user who has permission to `/home/stoysnet/`.